# Shared Element Transition between Recyclerview and Detailsfragment: elevation, hierarchy, bringToFront

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have some experience working with shared element transitions and fragment transition but I got stuck at the following problem.

I have a `RecyclerView` with items, if you click on one of the items it uses a `ChangeBounds` transition to go to the details page. This works fine. When I press the back button, the transition takes place again using the `ChangeBounds` transition. The only problem is when returning, the transition animates the item underneath the other items in the `RecyclerView`.

So what I'm trying to accomplish is the elevate the item above the other items when the return animation takes place. I tried elevating the shared element by using

```
setElevation(1000);
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect.

I tried everything I could find on the internet but there ain't much examples of this specific  problem.

Any feedback is welcome :)

Cheers!

Comment: I've just come across this problem myself. Did you find a good solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's to late, but for me it was relevant.
Tried many things to make it work not underneath other objects.

**The solution was to put `clipChildren='false'` to destination fragment layout for the whole hierarchy to shared element.**

In this case shared element could be drawn out of viewpager of other viewgroup that is not expanded to match parent.